# Check if variable is number: Applescript

Tags: macos, variables, numbers, applescript

How can I check if a variable is a number?

I'm trying this:

```
set a to 5
if a is a number
display dialog "Yes! It's a number!"
end if
```

I've also tried this code:

```
set a to 5
if a is integer
display dialog "Yes! It's a number!"
end if
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

class of a is integer will fail if you use

```
set a to "5"
```

This will work if even if the variable is a number but was entered as text.

```
set a to "5"
try
    set a to a as number
    display dialog "Yes! It's a number!"
end try
```

Comment: btw, this does not check for integer, it allows the user to input a "real" such as `set a to "5.5"`.  (as an aside, this is written as if it were a comment on my answer. maybe it should've been.)

Comment: The OP didn't ask for an integer. "How can I check if a variable is a number?"

Comment: @jpwagner A very likely use-case is where the input comes from a different script where all the input is untyped. Like me, I'm getting input from a bash script.

Answer (score 8):

```
set a to 5
if class of a is integer then
    display dialog "Yes! It's a number!"
end if
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution:

```
on is_number(number_string)
    try
        set number_string to number_string as number
        return true
    on error
        return false
    end try
end is_number
```