# Efficient string editing in Applescript

Tags: sed, terminal, applescript

I'm writing an applescript that needs to take a string and output just the numbers in that string. I have a method that works

`do shell script "sed s/[a-zA-Z\\']//g <<< " & s`

where s is the input string, but this script is doing this thousands of times and it ends up taking on the order of twenty minutes to get through them all. Is there any way I could make this faster?

Expected input is a string that can contain pretty much anything (except no `/` or `\`. I've tried to have there be no whitespace characters as that breaks my method, but sometimes I get one still). Expected output is a string of numbers (or an empty string). For example the sentence "1 man paid 1,23 cents for 51 cans of beer " would have the desired output of simply "112351", and "I h8 dealing with all these numb3rs" would output "83"

Comment: You'd save a lot of calls, if you could pass the whole text, and not just a string at a time. Just mentioning it.

Comment: Are you on 10.10+? If so, use `NSRegularExpression` via AppleScript-ObjC. Or use the third-party Satimage.osax's `find text` command, which works on earlier OS versions as well.

Comment: Can you provide input and expected output?

Comment: I need to keep the strings as separate entities. Is there a way to combine, filter, and then separate again?

Answer (score 2):

If you really have to pick the numbers from a string at a time, then maybe this approach is faster, even though it seems like a lot more, but I should tell you, that specifying the full path of the tr command, is something that will save some, if just some milliseconds.

```
set mlist to "1 man paid 1,23 cents for 51 can\\'s of beer "
 script o
    property l : missing value
 end script
 set o's l to words of mlist
 repeat with i from 1 to (count o's l)
    try
        item i of o's l as integer
    on error
        set item i of o's l to missing value
    end try
 end repeat
 set o's l to o's l's text

 set tids to my text item delimiters
 set my text item delimiters to space
 set o's l to text items of o's l
 set my text item delimiters to tids
 set o's l to o's l as text
 set my text item delimiters to ","
 set o's l to text items of o's l
 set my text item delimiters to tids
 set numb3rs to o's l as text

 log numb3rs
 --> (*112351*)
```

This approach may be faster, because you save the overhead of do shell script for every line you got, it should also just return the numbers, if those numbers are well formed (correct decimal separator). I haven't tried it with e-notation, but I think that should work as well.

Comment: +1 As McUsr says, repeating with do shell script will add lots of time. You should either process the entire text with 1 shell command or in vanilla AppleScript.

Comment: [Satimage osax](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/smile/text/reg_exp_syntax.html) that foo mentioned, in the comments above, is also a nifty command to perform filtering with. it is free, and it was last updated in june 2014, since it is an osaxen, it is more or less resident in memory all of the time once loaded, and requires a minimum of overhead. It also supports the following regexp syntaxes: **"POSIX", "POSIX_EXTENDED", "EMACS", "GREP", "GNU_REGEX", "JAVA", "PERL", "RUBY"** so it is also a highly sophisticated tool for using regexps.

Comment: Although this looks awesome, I really just need the numbers in a string with nothing else. For example the sentence `"1 man paid 1,23 cents for 51 cans of beer "` would have the desired output of simply `"112351"`. And `"I h8 dealing with all these numb3rs"` would output `"83"`

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `tr`?

```
 tr -d '[:alpha:][:punct:]' <<< string
```

Comment: This is definitely an improvement, it seems to have shaved 3-4 minutes off the run time.

Comment: glad to know this...I'll keep this in mind if someone else have ask this question..:D..

Comment: Even better, use the "complement" flag: tr -d -c '[0-9]' <<< string

Answer (score 0):

Another sed-solution, to make sure that only numbers are displayed:

```
do shell script "echo " & quoted form of s & "|sed s/[^0-9]//g"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is actually even slower.

Answer (score 0):

I offer this alternate code. I don't see why McUsr's code needs to be that complicated.

```
set s to "1 man paid 1,23 cents for 51 can\\'s of beer "
set n to ""

repeat with i from 1 to (length of s)
    set c to (character i of s)

    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313799
    if class of c is number then
        set n to n & c
    end if

end repeat

return n
```