# AppleScript check if list item's value is integer

Tags: string, list, integer, applescript

In AppleScript I'm trying to learn how to check the value of a list's items but when I try to check wether the item is an integer I get inaccurate results.  First I referenced [Apple's Automation scripting guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ManipulateListsofItems.html) under the section **Determining if a List Contains a Specific Item**:

```
property one : 1
property two : 2
property three : 3
property bad : 4

my checkProperty()

on checkProperty()
    tell application "Finder"
        set someList to {one, two, three, bad}
        if someList contains string then
            display dialog "good"
        else
            display dialog "not numerical"
        end if
    end tell
end checkProperty
```

When I execute this I get `not numerical` though every item is an integer.  If I reference [Applescript, converting every item in list to integer](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/applescript-converting-every-item-in-list-to-integer.1163814/) and execute:

```
property one : 1
property two : 2
property three : 3
property bad : "bad"

my checkProperty()

on checkProperty()
    tell application "Finder"
        set someList to {one, two, three, bad}
        repeat with theItem from 1 to length of someList
            set item theItem of someList to (item theItem of someList as integer)
            if theItem is integer then
                display dialog theItem
            else
                display dialog "not numerical"
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end checkProperty
```

It works until the last entry of the list (`bad`) and errors out since `theItem` can't convert the string to integer.  Searching on SO I ran across [Check if variable is number: Applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313799/check-if-variable-is-number-applescript) and tried the accepted answer with [number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20319349/1952287):

```
property one : 1
property two : 2
property three : 3
property bad : "bad"

my checkProperty()

on checkProperty()
    tell application "Finder"
        set someList to {one, two, three, bad}
        repeat with theItem from 1 to length of someList
            if class of theItem is number then
                display dialog theItem
            else
                display dialog "not numerical"
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end checkProperty
```

but when the script is ran it returns `not numerical` for every item.  If I try the second answer that uses [integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20313910/1952287):

```
if class of theItem is integer then
    display dialog theItem
else
    display dialog "not numerical"
end if
```

I get returned an individual dialog for counting the entries.  How can I check the value of a list item in AppleScript to see if it's an integer or a string without throwing an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test if all items in a list are a specific type:

```
to isListOfType(theList, theType)
  return (count {theList} each list) = 1 ¬
      and (count theList each theType) = (count theList)
end isListOfType

isListOfType({1, 2, 3}, integer) --> true
isListOfType({1, 2, 3, 4.5}, number) --> true
isListOfType({1, 2, 3, 4.5, "6"}, number) --> false
```

That said, it's usually much quicker and more convenient just to cast/coerce values as needed at the point they're used, and handle any errors at that time. e.g. `"4"` may be a string, but it's perfectly acceptable where an integer/real is expected, and AppleScript will generally coerce it for you so you don't have to do anything extra yourself.

(Caveat: some AppleScript coercions are lossy, e.g. `4.5 as integer` rounds to even (`4`) and `{a:1, b:2} as list` returns the properties' values (`{1, 2}`) rather than a single-item list (`{{a:1, b:2}}`), which may not be what you want. But honestly, if you need a really robust, reliable language then you shouldn't be using AppleScript anyway.)

--

p.s. The Scripting Essentials guide you linked to is garbage and best avoided. Half the samples aren't even wrong, and even the ones that are technically correct are often fragile and slow. You want some decent general-purpose value munging libraries, [try these](https://github.com/hhas/applescript-stdlib), and then go dupe [this ticket](http://openradar.appspot.com/28465563) on bugreport.apple.com asking Apple to adopt them for 10.13.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest playing with try/on error loops. I'm not at my mac atm, but try this:

```
property one : 1
property two : 2
property three : 3
property bad : "bad"

my checkProperty()

on checkProperty()
    tell application "Finder"
        set someList to {one, two, three, bad}
        repeat with theItem from 1 to length of someList
            try
                set item theItem of someList to (item theItem of someList as integer)
                display dialog theItem
            on error
                display dialog "not numerical"
            end try
        end repeat
    end tell
end checkProperty
```

Documentation on the [try/on error](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html).